# Asp.net Required Field Validator Issue

Tags: asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I am using `asp.net validations` and `jquery validation` for checking user input.I am using number of `required field validators` and `custom validators` in my form , i am facing a strange problem , when a field with `required validator` is empty , the `error message` is displayed on `validation summary`. this is all right.When the same field is left empty and wrong inputs are entered on other fields with `custom validators` ,, the `validation summary` only displays the `error message` of `required field validator`.The other error messages are just not displayed.Can anybody point me out where am i going wrong.
Thanks

Comment: I think we'll need to look at your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code sample that uses **RequiredFieldValidator** together with **CustomValidator**. It validates both fields, as well as when one of them fails, and displays the error messages in the **ValidationSummary**.

The *CustomValidator* has OnServerValidate function in the code behind.

The .aspx markup:

```
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <div>
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" EnableClientScript="false"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="The 'Name' field cannot be empty!" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    <br /><br />

                    <label>Number:</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ValidateEmptyText="true"
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="The 'Number' field must be exactly 5 digits!" Text="*" ForeColor="Red" 
                    Display="Dynamic" onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>

                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" HeaderText="Please check the following fields:" ForeColor="Red" DisplayMode="BulletList" />

                    <br />

                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

and the validation function in .aspx.cs file:

```
            protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
            {
                if (args.Value.Length < 5 || args.Value.Length > 5)
                {
                    args.IsValid = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    args.IsValid = true;
                }
            }
```

In order to be able to display both error messages, and not only the *RequiredFieldValidator*'s, its property 'EnableClientScript' should be set to false.

Hopefully, this will get you going and solve your problem.